# Construction of eigenfunction for Hecke operators $T_p$

Tags: modular-forms

I am reading Theorem 2 from Atkin-Lehner's [Hecke operators on $\Gamma_0(m)$](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01359701). Let $u=(u_1(\tau),u_2(\tau),..,u_n(\tau))$ be an orthonormal basis for the space of cusp forms on $\Gamma_0(m)$ with weight $k$. Let $A_p$ denote the matrix associated with each Hecke operator $T_p$ with respect to $u$. Then we take $A$ to be a unitary matrix which can simultaneously diagonalise all $A_p.$

Then how does it follow that each element of the new basis $f=Au$ is an eigenfunction of all the operators $T_p$?

My attempt: Need $T_p(f_i) = \lambda_pf_i$ for all $p$. Since $A$ can simultaneously diagonalise all $A_p,$ I have $A_p = ADA^{-1}$ ($D$ is diagonal). Then, right multiply with $Au$ leading to $A_p(Au) = ADA^{-1}Au, = ADu. $ I can't proceed further.

Will this construction of eigenforms work for any set of operators?

Let me know if any more clarifications are needed.

Comment: It is because the $T_p$ commute and $M_k(\Gamma_0(m))$ is finite dimensional, so there exists a basis $U$ where they are all in Jordan normal form, and they are normal for the Peterson inner product, so they are diagonal in $U$ and $U$ is unitary for that inner product. Can you copy the article ?

Comment: @reuns No I could not. I seem to miss a point somewhere. I will try with this insight and come back.

Comment: @reuns Let $f=Au$ with $f=f_1,f_2,\ldots$ and $u=u_1,u_2,\ldots.$ Then $ f|T_p = Au | T_p = A(A_pu) = (AA_pA^T)f = diag(\lambda_1(p),\lambda_2(p),\ldots)f. $ Is this true?